# Export table from html to excel with js (orentation problem)

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Cant pass orientation landscape parameter to excel, though can pass zoom parameter just fine

Tried to include @page solution,tried to pass page orientation parameter tried various examples and solutions.
PS: working with dynamical tables client side, the table itself passes fine with their values and even zoom parameter passes, problem it with orientation
Edited code, beginning was cut due to code checker

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
                template = '<html  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"' +
                    ' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">' +
                    '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"><head>' +
                    '<!--[if gte mso 9]>' +
                    '<xml><x:ExcelWorkbook>' +

                    '<x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
                    '<x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
                    '<x:Name>{worksheet}' +
                    '</x:Name>' +
                    '<x:WorksheetOptions>' +


                    '<x:Zoom>100</x:Zoom>'+

                    '<x:DisplayGridlines/>' +
                    '</x:WorksheetOptions>' +
                    '</x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
                    '</x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
                    '</x:ExcelWorkbook>' +
                    '</xml><![endif]-->' +
                    '</head><body><table><caption>{table}</caption></table></body></html>'
            base64 = function(s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
            },
                format = function(s, c) {
                    return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                        return c[p];
                    })
                }
            return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById("examplecopy")
                var ctx = {
                    worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
                    table: table.innerHTML
                }
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            }
        })()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

    var tableToExcel = (function() {

        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',

            template = '<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">'+
            '<head> <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet> <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 11">'+
           ' <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:DocumentProperties><o:Author>Pat Willener</o:Author><o:Company>Good Day Books</o:Company>'+
      '  </o:DocumentProperties><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:RelyOnVML/><o:AllowPNG/></o:OfficeDocumentSettings>'+
      '  </xml><![endif]-->'+
       ' <style><!--table {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}  @page {mso-header-data:"&CInventory";  mso-footer-data:"Page &P of &N";'+
           ' margin:.31in 0in .31in 0in;  mso-header-margin:0in;  mso-footer-margin:0in;  mso-page-orientation:landscape;}  --></style>'+
       ' <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>Inventory</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Print><x:ValidPrinterInfo/>'+
       ' <x:PaperSizeIndex>9</x:PaperSizeIndex><x:HorizontalResolution>600</x:HorizontalResolution><x:VerticalResolution>600</x:VerticalResolution></x:Print><x:Selected/>'+
       ' <x:Panes><x:Pane><x:Number>1</x:Number><x:ActiveRow>1</x:ActiveRow></x:Pane></x:Panes><x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents><x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>'+
        '<x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets><x:WindowHeight>8835</x:WindowHeight><x:WindowWidth>15180</x:WindowWidth>'+
       ' <x:WindowTopX>120</x:WindowTopX><x:WindowTopY>105</x:WindowTopY><x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure><x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows></x:ExcelWorkbook>'+
        '</xml><![endif]-->'+

       ' <title>Inventory</title>'+

                '</head><body><table><caption>{table}</caption></table></body></html>'
        base64 = function(s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        },
            format = function(s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                })
            }
        return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById("examplecopy")
            var ctx = {
                worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
                table: table.innerHTML
            }
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
    })()

</script>
```

this one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
      var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
      }
    })()
    </script>
```